# SQL INSERT INTO statement with WHERE Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Can you use a WHERE statement within an INSERT INTO statement in SQL?

here is what i am currently trying to do.

```
INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription)
VALUES (@ComponentType, @CompDescr)
WHERE (AssetTagNumber = @TagNo)
```

But the compiler is having an issue with the WHERE statement.

thanks

******UPDATE***********

This is the full code that i am using so far with amendments

```
   protected void AddBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //still passing the Asset tag number forward here
        var ID = Request.QueryString["Id"];

        string sql = "";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source: *******************)
        {

            sql = "IF (AssetTagNumber = @TagNo) " +
                   "BEGIN " +
                   "INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription) " + 
                   "VALUES (@ComponentType, @CompDescr) " +
                   "END ";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {

              //  try
               // {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNo", ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComponentType", TypeDDL.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompDescr", DescrTB.Text.Trim());

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Redirect("ComponentDetails.aspx");
             //   }
            //    catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show(" "); }
            //    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(" "); }
            }
        }
    }
```

Im sorry i was not clear enough first time around.

What i want to do is insert a new record with a clause that says if this record has an existing PK then use this key to insert another entry for that record

Apologies once again

Comment: why not using Update instead

Comment: you forgot the SELECT ....

Comment: Your INSERT doesn't know WHERE to get the data from.

Comment: Where cannot work with Insert. Use IF before insertion

Comment: I cant use Update because it is a new record being added, Where would SELECT come in useful in this situation?

Comment: What do you want to express adding a WHERE to an INSERT. Do you have a condition that inhibits the inserting a new record? Please be more clear on your intentions.

Comment: Ah i hadnt realised that you could not use Insert with WHERE, i will try IF

Comment: @user2500842 You can insert into one table the results of a `SELECT` from another table as in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE ...`. In that case, the `WHERE` condition applies to the `SELECT` and determines the subset of records from the second table to insert into the first.

Comment: Sounds to me like you simply want to insert a record: `INSERT INTO AssetComponents(AssetTagNumber, ComponentID, ComponentDescription) VALUES (@TagNo, @ComponentType, @CompDescr)`

Comment: Yes although not quite as simple as that haha, basically there will be a number of records with the same PK which is "AssetTagNumber"

Comment: Umm, there cannot by definition be more than one record with the same PK...?

Comment: It sounds confusing. Okay basically there will be a pc with a unique pc name, but what i need to do is add hardware to that specific pc using the pc name

Comment: @user2500842,have a look at my answer.

Comment: Here you can see an example:http://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/conditional-insert-query-based-on-data-in-target-table/

Comment: This looks interesting!

Comment: @user2500842 Based on your last comment, it sound like you should have two tables. One for the PC, one for hardware. Hardware table should have a foreign key column referencing the PK from PC table... Then first insert the row(s) to the PC table, then insert rows to the harware table, with the correct PK value from PC table included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use IF-clause?

```
IF (AssetTagNumber = @TagNo)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription)
    VALUES (@ComponentType, @CompDescr)
END
```

For statements with WHERE script should look similar to:

```
INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription)
SELECT @ComponentType, @CompDescr
FROM <table>
WHERE (AssetTagNumber = @TagNo)
```

Comment: Thanks i didnt know of this clause, i am new to SQL after years of neglect

Comment: Yes .. this makes more sense ! !

Answer (score 2):

You can not "conditionally insert" like that. The `WHERE` clause is only available for `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

To check whether you need to `INSERT` a new record, you need to use `IF`, as in:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
    INSERT INTO ...
```

Comment: Yes this seems to be more along the lines of what i need, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
if EXISTS (select * from AssetComponents where AssetTagNumber = @TagNo)

Begin

INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription)
(@ComponentType, @CompDescr)

End
```

Comment: This does not work. AssetTagNumber is a column in my database that is causing this error ------> "Invalid column name 'AssetTagNumber'."

Comment: Please try edited answer, hope it works, if exists or if not exists as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
UPDATE AssetComponents     
Set ComponentID=@ComponentType, ComponentDescription=@CompDesc    
Where AssetTagNumber = @TagNo
```

Comment: What makes you all think he actually wants to update? What if he wants to conditionally insert?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause is something that helps to filter record, so it preferably uses with either `SELECT` or `UPDATE`. For `INSERT` we normally use `IF NOT EXISTS` clause.

See Examples:

> 1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/724ab6f3-413f-4c59-9b68-776f3ecfa899/insert-if-not-exists-into
> 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Also, after [looking at documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), we can see that `INSERT` statement has **NO** support for `WHERE` clause.

If records already exists you can perform eith `UPDATE` or `DELETE` with `INSERT` operations.

You can try like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AssetComponents WHERE (AssetTagNumber = @TagNo))
 INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription) VALUES (@ComponentType, @CompDescr)
ELSE
 --UPDATE fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider INSERT SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO AssetComponents(ComponentID, ComponentDescription)
SELECT [fill out here] AS ComponentID,
       [fill out here] AS ComponentDescription
FROM somesource
WHERE [condition]
```

This is a specialty of MS SQL Server so will not work in other databases. It sort of requires that your data are already in another table or other source that you can query.